# Is this a sufficient proof for showing that if matrices commute, their inverses commute?

Tags: matrices, inverse

If not, where am I going wrong, or am I assuming something that isn't true?

$AB=BA$, then $\left(B^{-1}A^{-1}\right)^{-1}=\left(A^{-1}B^{-1}\right)^{-1}$ so $B^{-1}A^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$.

Comment: It's one way of doing it...

Comment: Cool! Because my textbook's method is long-winded and I thought I must have assumed something incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Potentially confusing title: you're showing that **if** $A, B$ commute **then** $A^{-1}, B^{-1}$ also commute. Intuitive method though, well done.

Comment: Good point, changed, and thanks!

Comment: Well, first of all you must assume the existence of inverses. Then: $$AB=BA\implies (AB)^{-1}=(BA)^{-1}\implies \dots$$